# Accepting file names with a single dot in Java using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to set-up a program that accepts a valid file name as such:

"File.pdf" -- VALID

"File..pdf" -- INVALID (or more numbers of dots/periods)

".pdf" -- INVALID

"File.Drop.pdf" -- INVALID

Here is what I have so far:

```
 if (name.equals(("^\\b([a-zA-Z]+\\.+)\\b$"))){  
  this.name = name;
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong here, but any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to do it with regex ? not other solutions ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi it does not have to be with RegEx, but I would prefer to get familiar with RegEx. Out of curiosity, how would you accomplish this?

Comment: check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression would be:

```
if (name.matches("^\\w+\\.\\w+$")) {  
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: what about `p123.p1` ?

Comment: Also, note that in this case, matching on word boundaries with `\b` is redundant, but I left them in there as it doesn't affect the expression.

Comment: I modified the expression to match on any valid "word" character with `\w`. Using `\w` is the equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: Your answer does exactly what I need it to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

here is some solutions :

1- Guava's [CharMatcher](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) API is quite powerful and concise:

```
CharMatcher.is('.').countIn("test.pdf"); //returns 1
```

2 - calculating differences between strings have `.` or not

```
String string = "test.pdf";
int count = string.length() - string.replaceAll("\\.", "").length();
```

3 - Try using [Apache Commons' StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html):

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("test.pdf", '.');
```

4 - use the regex :

```
String str = "test.pdf";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str); 
System.out.println(str);
int count = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    if(str.charAt(m.start())=='.') count++;
}
System.out.println(count); // will print 1
```

Comment: thank you for the multiple solutions. I will try out some of the first methods you suggested (in particular method 2) in order to see how this can be completed without RegEx. Thanks again!

Comment: So check my answer as true

Comment: If you find it more useful than other solutions